# Measuring untyped-javascript -> typescript conversion progress?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ok, so I'm completely sold on the idea of TypeScript and I want to use it for an already existing software project. Now, as Typescript is a superset of javascript, it means that I can start by renaming all files to have .ts extension instead of `.js`, and then gradually start converting.

However, I'm not alone in the team so it might happen that I convert bit by bit, but other developers keep increasing the codebase size with naughty untyped JavaScript in the .ts files.

Then my idea would be to have a way to measure how much percentage of real TypeScript (non JavaScript) a project has, to avoid, via continuous integration (e.g. breaking the build when the rate of TS decreases), that we go backwards.

Is this possible? Can the typescript compiler by any chance give already this kind of statistics?

Comment: Are you saying you want to compare the number of literal .ts vs. .js files?

Comment: write an utilitary that checks the number of files or the number of lines in the files.. how to do it though it's a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: Just don't rename your JavaScript files until you've converted them to TypeScript. It's not like you can't mix the two...

Comment: @DrewQuick sorry, what? there would be no .js files at all

Comment: @toskv read the question again, all files would be .ts

Comment: @knocte .ts compiles down to .js.  I.E. without .js, your project wouldn't work.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but then someone might introduce javascript in a typescript file by mistake

Comment: @DrewQuick the .js files would be autogenerated; I'm talking about the .ts files in my repository

Comment: @knocte  It might help to know what environment you're working with.  If we talking a common IDE like Visual Studio, you're going to compile your typescript down to javascript either before or at runtime

Comment: @knocte javascript in a typescript file is typescript.. you need to define a more specific metric..

Comment: in a way once you rename the flies to ts you've got 100% typescript conversion. :P

Comment: @knocte toskv is right.  TS will inherit JS.  JS will NOT inherit TS.  So if we're talking a web app, you have to compile your typescript down to javascript.  For now at least.

Comment: @knocte That's the easiest way of accomplishing your task. Also, once you rename all of your .js files to .ts, you've got nothing but JavaScript in your TypeScript files...

Comment: @DrewQuick I don't know what does the TS->JS conversion have to do with this question

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan right, but my goal is to have TypeScript that is not JavaScript, I guess that thing needs a new name...

Comment: @knocte  I'm just trying to assist but given the amount of details, I'm assuming you're using a source control like TFS or Git.  You can't compare raw text because js within a ts file is the same.  TS just extends js.  There is also the part where you will have a js file for every ts file.  If you are level on both fields (10 ts files & 10 js files) then the assumption would be that you are fully converted.

Comment: dude, forget the .js files generated by the ts compiler, I'm not talking about those

Comment: @knocte As far as trying to prevent other people from entering "naughty javascript", you just need to ensure that they are working off of the ts files going forward.

Comment: that's not true, they can write untyped javascript inside the .ts files and the typescript compiler will not complain

Comment: @knocte OK then! Now we're getting somewhere.  So what you really mean to ask is, how do I compare the amount of untyped JS within  TS file vs. other.  In which case, I don't have an answer for you.  Good luck!

Comment: well, then don't comment... this is possibly a feature request that I should file on typescript's compiler bugtracker I guess

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you want to measure how type-safe your code is. Short answer: I don't know any easy way, tell me if you find something :-)

The thing is, even if your javascript is untyped, it does not mean it's not typechecked when you compile it with typescript. Typescript compiler can often infer types for untyped javascript code:

```
function f() {
    return { a: 'a', b: 1 };
}

var x = f();
var y = x.b;

var z = x.c; // error
y = y + '1'; // error
```

It definitely makes life easier for developers, but it means that it's not that easy to measure what you want. One thing that you can do is try to compile your project with `--noImplicitAny` and count how many errors it produces - this will give you all the places where compiler was unable to infer a sensible type and just went with `any`. Also, you can catch all instances where something is declared with `any` that essentially bypass typechecking by using tslint [no-any](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/) rule.

But in a real project you typically also have a number of dependencies that have not-so-strict typings, either by necessity or just because they are imperfect. And I don't think there is a way to tell if `any` appeared because your developer added code that's not type safe, or it was because some third-party dependency need it that way.

Comment: `And I don't think there is a way to tell if any appeared because your developer added code that's not type safe, or it was because some third-party dependency need it that way.` well, if I run it once, and I keep that number, I could make sure that the CI build just checks this number is not raising, right?

Comment: I'm thinking of scenario where just using some API with less than ideal typings will cause this number to increase. Not sure how realistic it is. Also, developers can add type casts to suppress these kinds of errors, and there is no way to tell if type cast is safe or not, short of reviewing the code.